# Cant create login on sql server 2000

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm running the below sql

```
USE MASTER
CREATE LOGIN [map] WITH PASSWORD=N'password'
GO
```

and I get this:

```
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Line 2: Incorrect syntax near 'LOGIN'.
```

Any thoughts?

Cheers,
Mark.

Comment: Works for me, how/with what are you running it?

Comment: Alex, I think your edit has changed the SQL and removed the problem!

Comment: I've re-titled and re-tagged. The error is now clearly because `CREATE LOGIN` syntax didn't exist in SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're executing this (SSMS?) you've a couple of options:

1: Don't do the `USE MASTER` at all.

2: Separate into lines:

```
USE MASTER
CREATE LOGIN [map] WITH PASSWORD=N'password'
```

3: Separate commands with `;`

```
USE MASTER; CREATE LOGIN [map] WITH PASSWORD=N'password'
```

Comment: Thanks John. Apparently I need to use sp_addlogin because its a sql 2000 db.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in a compatibility for an older version of SQL Server?  Run:

```
select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name = 'YourDatabase'
```

Values of compability levels and their corresponding MS SQL Server versions are as follows:

```
60 = SQL Server 6.0 
65 = SQL Server 6.5 
70 = SQL Server 7.0 
80 = SQL Server 2000 
90 = SQL Server 2005
100 = SQL Server 2008
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Its a sql 2000 db. I'm using 2008 SSMS. I do have it separated into lines and it just got formatted that way in the post. Even when I have it on separate lines it still errors. Is there a method of scripting logins on a sql server 2000 database? I don't seem to have the object sys.databases.

Comment: Apparently for sql 2000 I need to use sp_addlogin. Thanks all.